# How to add a namespace to existing xml file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to open this file and get all elements that start with `us-gaap`.

```
ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/916789/0001558370-15-001143.txt
```

To get elements I tried like this:

```
str = '<html><body><us-gaap:foo>foo</us-gaap:foo></body></html>'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(str))
doc.xpath('//us-gaap:*')
Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Undefined namespace prefix: //us-gaap:*
from /Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:165:in `evaluate'
```

`doc.namespaces` returns `{}`, so I think I have to add namespace `us-gaap`.

There are some questions about "adding namespace with Nokogiri", but it looks like about how to create a new XML document, not how to add a namespace to existing documents.

How can I add a namespace to existing document?

I know I can remove the namespace by `Nokogiri::XML::Document#remove_namespaces!`, but I don't want to use it because it removes also necesarry information.

Comment: Instead of a link, extract the minimal data to demonstrate the problem and put it into your question. What code have you written to solve this problem? Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimal input and an example of the output you want.

Comment: Thanks for warning, I add a minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153741). You think that the problem is that you need to add a missing namespace; the real problem is that the file you're trying to parse is not valid XML.

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML( IO.read('0001558370-15-001143.txt') )
doc.errors.length
#=> 5716
```

For example, the `<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>` 'element' opened on line 3 is never closed, and on line 16 there is a raw ampersand in the text:
`STANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION:    ELECTRIC HOUSEWARES & FANS [3634]`
which ought to be escaped as an entity.

However, the document has valid XML fragments *within* it! In particular, there is one XML document that defines `xmlns:us-gaap` namespace, from lines 27243-49312. Let's extract just that, using only the knowledge that the root element defines the namespace we want, and the **assumptions** that no element with the same name is nested within the document, and that the root element does not have an unescaped `>` character in any attribute. (These assumptions are valid for this file, but may not be valid for every XML file.)

```ruby
txt = IO.read('0001558370-15-001143.txt')
gaap_finder = %r{(<(\w+) [^>]+xmlns:us-gaap=.+?</\2>)}m
txt.scan(gaap_finder) do |xml,_|
  doc = Nokogiri.XML( xml )
  gaaps = doc.xpath('//us-gaap:*')
  p gaaps.length
  #=> 569
end
```

The code above handles the case where there may be more than one XML document in the txt file, though in this case there is only one.

Decoded, the `gaap_finder` regex says this:

- `%r{...}m` — this is a regular expression (that allows slashes in it, unescaped) with "multiline mode", where a period will match newline characters
- `(...)` — capture everything we find
- `<` — start with a literal "less-than" symbol
- `(\w+)` — find one or more word characters (the tag name), and save them
- — the word characters must be followed by a space (important to avoid capturing the `<xsd:xbrl ...>` element in this file)
- `[^>]+` — followed by one or more characters that is NOT a "greater-than" symbol (to ensure that we stay in the same element that we started in)
- `xmlns:us-gaap\s*=` — followed by this literal namespace declaration (which may have whitespace separating it from the equals sign)
- `.+?` — followed by anything (as little as possible)...
- `</\2>` — ...up until you see a closing tag with the same name as what we captured for the name of the starting tag

Because of the way `scan` works when the regex has capturing groups, each result is a two-element array, where the first element is the entire captured XML and the second element is the name of the tag that we captured (which we "discard" by assigning it to the `_` variable).

---

If you want to be less magic about your capturing, the text file format appears to always wrap each XML document in `<XBRL>...</XBRL>`. So, you could do this to process every XML file (there are seven, five of which do not happen to have any `us-gaap` namespaces):

```ruby
txt   = IO.read('0001558370-15-001143.txt')
xbrls = %r{(?<=<XBRL>).+?(?=</XBRL>)}m      # find text inside <XBRL>…</XBRL>
txt.scan(xbrls) do |xml|
  doc = Nokogiri.XML( xml )
  if doc.namespaces["xmlns:us-gaap"]
    gaaps = doc.xpath('//us-gaap:*')
    p gaaps.length
  end
end
#=> 569
#=> 0        (for the XML Schema document that defines the namespace)
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure out how to update an existing doc with a new namespace, but since Nokogiri will recognize namespaces on the root element, and those namespaces are, syntactically, just attributes, you can update the document with a new namespace declaration, serialize the doc to a string, and re-parse it:

```ruby
str = '<html><body><us-gaap:foo>foo</us-gaap:foo></body></html>'
doc_without_ns = Nokogiri::XML(str)
doc_without_ns.root['xmlns:us-gaap'] = 'http://your/actual/ns/here'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(doc_without_ns.to_xml)
doc.xpath("//us-gaap:*")
# Returns [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff375583f9c name="foo" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3ff375583f24 prefix="us-gaap" href="http://your/actual/ns/here"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff375583768 "foo">]>]
```

Comment: This is an interesting hack for a valid XML document (which the OP included as the sample code). However, the original document is not a valid XML document, so this won't solve the real-world problem. I'd upvote you for the first, but downvote you for the second, so the net result is no change. :/

Comment: The question asked by the OP was "How can I add a namespace to existing document?". He indicated that the Nokogiri XPath query gave an empty result, which implies that he was already able to parse the information he wanted as an XML document. So, I answered that question.

So basically, you're suggesting that you'd downvote me based on your own assumption that the OP didn't correctly describe his problem. That's you're prerogative, but I think it's incorrect.

Comment: You get an upvote for being polite and reasonable, and for answering the question put in the title. But I don't think mine is an assumption. Look at the first two lines of the question. Then open the document. Then try to work with it. As noted in my answer, you'll find that it doesn't work because it's not an XML document, and parsing it as such is a higgledy-piggledy mess. The only reason there's the misleading example is because TheTinMan asked the OP to add one, and the OP then added code that unfortunately does not match the real problem.